# Error: The type or namespace name 'Z3' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#, ubuntu-18.04, z3

First I apologize for the awful English, I'm new in Ubuntu.I tried installing Spire in Ubuntu and after installing z3 and PSI, I got the following error to install Spire.

```
"/home/mahdieh/Spire-master/Spire.sln" (default target) (1) ->`"/home/mahdieh/Spire-master/Spire/Spire.csproj" (default target) (2) ->
(CoreCompile target) -> 
  PolicySynthesis.cs(17,17): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Z3' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [/home/mahdieh/Spire-master/Spire/Spire.csproj]
  Synthesize.cs(17,17): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Z3' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [/home/mahdieh/Spire-master/Spire/Spire.csproj]
```

Could anyone please help me, I have no idea what to do :(

Comment: Spire:
https://github.com/eth-sri/Spire

Comment: Have you tried the Nuget package here https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Z3.x64/ ?

Comment: it did not work